# How to submit @using (Html.BeginForm()) and submit its content to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send 6 values from 6 different text boxes to the controller.  How can I do this without using JavaScript?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Admin"))
    {
@Html.TextBox(ValueRegular.ToString(FORMAT), new { @name = "PriceValueRegularLunch" })
@Html.TextBox(ValueRegular1.ToString(FORMAT), new { @name = "PriceValueRegularLunch1" })
@Html.TextBox(ValueRegular2.ToString(FORMAT), new { @name = "PriceValueRegularLunch2" })

        <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
}


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SavePrices(int PriceValueRegularLunch)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Lunch", "Home");
        }
```

Comment: Try making use of model also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what your controller should look like:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SavePrices(int PriceValueRegularLunch, 
        int PriceValueRegularLunch1, 
        int PriceValueRegularLunch2, 
        int PriceValueRegularLunch3, 
        int PriceValueRegularLunch4, 
        int PriceValueRegularLunch5)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Lunch", "Home");
    }
}
```

And your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SavePrices", "Admin"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("PriceValueRegularLunch")
    @Html.TextBox("PriceValueRegularLunch1")
    @Html.TextBox("PriceValueRegularLunch2")
    @Html.TextBox("PriceValueRegularLunch3")
    @Html.TextBox("PriceValueRegularLunch4")
    @Html.TextBox("PriceValueRegularLunch5")

    <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
}
```